# How to create/insert product programmatically in Websphere Commerce 7 WCS7

Tags: websphere-commerce, wcs

I'm developing an ecommerce based on Websphere Commerce 7 WCS7. I need to import products from an external supplier, which is exposing a webservice. I've already implemented a Controller Command performing all the operation needed to extract the products from the remote service, and I've them avalaible as custom Java classes.

I'm a little bit confused about the approach I should follow in this case. I've defined the attributes needed in my scenario and used the dataload utility to import them in the DB. What should I do next? I expect to be able to "create" WCS product programmatically from my Controller Command but I don't know how to use the attribute I've defined in a programmatic insert.

Can someone point me on the right track on how to perform this kind of operation? I went through the documentation, but, given the fact I'm quite new of the WCS environment, I don't know how to proceed according to the current best practices.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a new catalog entry programmatically if you copy what is being done in the LOBTools.  I have not done this myself though.  I have always added new products via the data loads and when we did need to add from an external service I just output the information to a file and loaded along with our other products.  The reason was due to keeping the catalog in sync with the product management system.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the various DataBean classes in WCS, like: CatalogEntryDataBean.

See here for WCS data beans:[Link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/concepts/csddtbns.htm?cp=SSZLC2_7.0.0%2F9-1-0-1&lang=en)

And here for "activation" of a DataBean:[Link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/concepts/csdruntime.htm?cp=SSZLC2_7.0.0)